# Problem with modules and importing folders

Tags: go, go-modules

I have some problems with how Go importing and modules works.
I have a project with this structure:

```
My-Project
|- Program 1
   |- main.go
   |- go.mod
|- Program 2
   |- main.go
   |- go.mod
|- Support
   |- go_file.go
```

The two programs have different module "definition". I need to include the "Support" folder, which is shared between the two programs. I tried

```
import "My-Project/Support"
```

inside Program1's main.go, but this is not working, because Support can’t be resolved. How can I do it?

Comment: what is the name of a package in `Support/go_file.go`?

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description. What error or other unexpected output do you see? What did you expect to see instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given, your `Support/go_file.go` is not in any module so it's not importable using Go modules.

Either use a single module for all three packages or use three separate modules (i.e. put Support in it's own module). You could also use sub-modules.

#### Single module:

For a single module you'd do something like:

```
└── My-Project
    ├── go.mod
    ├── Program\ 1
    │   └── main.go
    ├── Program\ 2
    │   └── main.go
    └── Support
        └── go_file.go
```

And the project level `go.mod` would be something like:

```
module github.com/My-Name/My-Project
```

(substitute with appropriate module name) and then both `main` packages would import the support package with:

```
import "github.com/My-Name/My-Project/Support"
```

Note Go packages normally do not start with capitals like this.

More idiomatic for such a setup with a single repository which mixes packages and commands is a layout that puts commands into a `cmd` subdirectory (e.g. see the [`golang.org/x/tools`](https://github.com/golang/tools/) layout). This would look something like this:

```
└── My-Project
    ├── cmd
    │   ├── program1
    │   │   └── main.go
    │   └── program2
    │       └── main.go
    ├── go.mod
    ├── internal
    │   └── support
    │       └── support.go
    └── other-package
        └── some-other-package.go
```

Here the `support` package is in an internal sub-directory which makes it non-importable from outside `My-Project` where-as the `other-package` is importable by anyone.

Again, `go.mod` would define the module name which sets the prefix to be used for all import statements.

#### Separate modules:

To use separate modules you'd do something like:

```
└── My-Project
    ├── Program\ 1
    │   ├── go.mod
    │   └── main.go
    ├── Program\ 2
    │   ├── go.mod
    │   └── main.go
    └── Support
        ├── go_file.go
        └── go.mod
```

Here `My-Project/Program 1/go.mod` would be something like:

```
module "github.com/My-Name/My-Project/Program 1"

require (
        github.com/My-Name/My-Project/Support
)
```

The imports would be the same as for the single module example.
Similarly for `Program 2`. For `Support/go.mod` it'd look something like:

```
module github.com/My-Name/My-Project/Support
```

For local development you'll probably also want/need a `replace` directive in each program's `go.mod` to use your local working copy of the support module (`go mod edit -replace github.com/My-Name/My-Project/Support=../Support` should add this).

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer! I solved the problem!